# What's the point of local variable in the HashMap.getNode(Object key) method

Tags: java

Looking at `HashMap.getNode(Object key)` method in OpenJDK we see a local variables `tab` initialized by assigning the `transient Node<K,V>[] table;` field to it:

```
final Node<K,V> getNode(Object key) {
    Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> first, e; int n, hash; K k;
    if ((tab = table) != null && (n = tab.length) > 0 &&
        (first = tab[(n - 1) & (hash = hash(key))]) != null) {
             ...
```

What's the benefit of assigning `table` field into `tab` local variable?

Why later in the code it's `first = tab[...]` instead of `first = table[...]`?